# Настройка apache2 конфига для Django

Tags: django, apache, apache2

Подскажите, вот с двох мануалов собрал один конфиг для apache2 и почему-то один конфиг перекрывает все поддомены, хотя ему выделил только один. Помогите решить проблему, не хочеться еще один домен добавлять((

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/django.conf`:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess project_name python-path=/var/www/html/project_name python-home=/var/www/html/project_name/venv
WSGIProcessGroup project_name
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName django.my_domain
        ServerAlias django.my_domain

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /var/www/html/project_name/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/project_name/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/project_name/project_name>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        #Require all granted
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        #WSGIDaemonProcess project_name python-path=/var/www/html/project_name python-home=/var/www/html/project_name/venv
        #WSGIProcessGroup project_name
        #WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =django.my_domain
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

SSL сертификат от certbot:
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/django-le-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName django.my_domain
        ServerAlias django.my_domain

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /var/www/html/my_project/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/my_project/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        #<Directory /var/www/html/my_project/my_project/wsgi.py>
        #       Order allow,deny
        #       Allow from all
        #</Directory>   
        <Directory /var/www/html/my_project/my_project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        #Require all granted
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        #WSGIDaemonProcess my_project python-path=/var/www/html/my_project python-home=/var/www/html/my_project/venv
        #WSGIProcessGroup my_project
        #WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/my_project/my_project/wsgi.py

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/django.my_domain/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/django.my_domain/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

И на всякий случай - wsgi.py:

```py
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/my_project')
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/my_project/my_project')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```